# Improved quoting of code

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-norepro

The markdown parser mangles code inside <pre> tags and white space. this becomes quite apparent when posting code that is sensitive to white space, such as self printing code. I made a little one line tool to help, but it is still anoying. `sed 's/^/   /' quinine |xclip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try indenting each line by 4 spaces instead of writing `<pre>` tags manually. You can do this easily by selecting the block of code and clicking the `{}` button in the editor toolbar, or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: Indeed this helps, and is basically what my little script does (although it uses a tab), but this is an error prone method to do by hand, which is why I wrote a script. ponder for a moment a brief script of 15 lines. If the pre tags worked it would be nine characters and only two places to make a mistake instead of 60 characters and at least fifteen places to make a mistake. The place that gave me the most trouble is long lines, I kept trying to add four spaces at the wrap.

Comment: @hildred It's not "error-prone", in that you highlight the block and click the `{}` button in the editor toolbar (or press Ctrl-K). Lemme suggest the same thing in the answer prose itself. :-)

Comment: Ah, at last something that the toolbar does better than just typing it in. That is the piece of information I was missing.